# Uncaught TypeError: SpeechKITT.displayRecognizedSentence is not a function

Tags: javascript, typeerror, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, annyang

I am using annyang.js for speech recognition but my
`SpeechKITT.displayRecognizedSentence` is not working I Tried by downloading the annyang library in local folder but nothing works for me please anyone help me with this
my full code

```
var commands = {
  'hello': function() { alert('Hello world!'); }
};

// Add our commands to annyang
annyang.addCommands(commands);

// Tell KITT to use annyang
SpeechKITT.annyang();

// Stylesheet for KITT to use
SpeechKITT.setStylesheet('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/SpeechKITT/1.0.0/themes/flat.css');

SpeechKITT.setInstructionsText('Some commands to try…');

SpeechKITT.setSampleCommands(['say Hello, Ok google etc..']);

SpeechKITT.displayRecognizedSentence(true);

// When start
SpeechKITT.setStartCommand(function() {
  console.info('Speech Recognition Started ______________________________');
  annyang.start();
});

// When abort
SpeechKITT.setAbortCommand(function() {
  console.info('Stopping ............................');
  annyang.abort();
});

// Render KITT's interface
SpeechKITT.vroom();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the library issue, there is the old issue on github about that (https://github.com/TalAter/SpeechKITT/issues/42)

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i saw some projects that using annyang and its working flawlessly on there Example:https://github.com/patrickjquinn/P-Brain.ai

Comment: is there any good alternative for annyang?